# How to align these sets of equations?

Tags: typography

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
h_1(t)&=b_{11}(t)+\sum_{j\neq 1}\lvert b_{1 j}(t)\rvert\\[1ex]
&=-(\beta_A A+\beta_I I+\rho)+\beta_A S- (\gamma_A+\sigma+\gamma_I+\eta+\alpha+2\mu)+\frac{R'}{R}+ \xi\frac{R}{S}\\[1ex]
&=\beta S - (\gamma_A+\sigma+\gamma_I+\eta+\alpha+\mu)-\frac{b(1-\nu)}{S}+\frac{S'}{S}+\frac{R'}{R}\\[1ex]
&\leq \beta_A-\gamma_A-\sigma-\gamma_I-\eta-\alpha-\mu+\frac{S'}{S}+\frac{R'}{R}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
h_2(t)&= b_{22}(t)+\sum_{j\neq 2}\lvert b_{2 j}(t)\rvert\\[1ex]
&= -(\beta_A A+\beta_I I+\rho)+\beta_A S- (\gamma_A+\sigma+\xi+2\mu)+\frac{I'}{I}+  c (\gamma_I+\eta) \frac{I}{R}+c\beta_I \frac{S I}{A}\\
&+c\beta_I I\\[1ex]
&\leq  -\epsilon \beta_A - \rho-\xi-\mu+c(\xi+\mu)+\frac{I'}{I}+c\frac{A'}{A}+c\frac{R'}{R}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
h_3(t)&= b_{33}(t)+\sum_{j\neq 3}\lvert b_{3 j}(t)\rvert\\[1ex]
&= -(\beta_A A+\beta_I I+\rho)-(\gamma_I+\eta+\alpha+\xi+2\mu)+\frac{A'}{A}+\gamma_A\frac{A}{R}+ \sigma\frac{A}{c I}  +\beta_A A\\[1ex]
&\leq  -\epsilon \beta_I - \rho-\gamma_I-\eta-\alpha-\mu+\frac{\gamma_I+\eta+\alpha+\mu}{c}+\frac{A'}{A}+c\frac{I'}{c I}+c\frac{R'}{R}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
h_4(t)&= b_{44}(t)+\sum_{j\neq 4}\lvert b_{4 j}(t)\rvert\\[1ex]
&=  \beta_A S -(\gamma_A + \sigma+\gamma_I+\eta+\alpha+\xi+2\mu)+\frac{S'}{S} +\rho\frac{S}{R}+ \beta_I \frac{S I}{A}\\[1ex]
&\leq  \beta_A-\gamma_I-\eta-\alpha+\frac{S'}{S}+\frac{A'}{A}+\frac{R'}{R}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The h_4 is not aligned with the rest, how can I do this?

If I align these all together, it will fix my above question but will leave a "space" in my document as they would run into a fresh page, so how can I align them without the space leftover?

Comment: you should never have one `align` followed by another: just use one, and use `\allowdisplaybreaks`in he preamble to allowpage breaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently using four [4!] consecutive, independent `align*` environments. The fact that the first three happen to look like they're aligned with each other is pure coincidence.

I suggest you use a *single* `align*` environment. In case you need to allow page breaks, I suggest you insert `\displaybreak[0]` directives where appropriate. Alternatively, if you wish to allow page breaks *anywhere* in the `align*` material, just issue the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
\addtolength\jot{2pt} % extra spacing between rows of display math
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert % absolute-value macro

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
h_1(t)&=b_{11}(t)+\sum\nolimits_{j\neq 1} \abs{b_{1 j}(t)} \\
&=-(\beta_A A+\beta_I I+\rho)+\beta_A S- (\gamma_A+\sigma+\gamma_I+\eta+\alpha+2\mu)+\frac{R'}{R}+ \xi\frac{R}{S}\\
&=\beta S - (\gamma_A+\sigma+\gamma_I+\eta+\alpha+\mu)-\frac{b(1-\nu)}{S}+\frac{S'}{S}+\frac{R'}{R}\\
&\leq \beta_A-\gamma_A-\sigma-\gamma_I-\eta-\alpha-\mu+\frac{S'}{S}+\frac{R'}{R} \displaybreak[0] \\[2ex]
%\end{align*}
%\begin{align*}
h_2(t)&= b_{22}(t)+\sum\nolimits_{j\neq 2} \abs{b_{2 j}(t)} \\
&= -(\beta_A A+\beta_I I+\rho)+\beta_A S- (\gamma_A+\sigma+\xi+2\mu)+\frac{I'}{I}+  c (\gamma_I+\eta) \frac{I}{R}\\
&\qquad+c\beta_I \frac{S I}{A}+c\beta_I I\\
&\leq  -\epsilon \beta_A - \rho-\xi-\mu+c(\xi+\mu)+\frac{I'}{I}+c\frac{A'}{A}+c\frac{R'}{R} \displaybreak[0]\\[2ex]
%\end{align*}
%\begin{align*}
h_3(t)&= b_{33}(t)+\sum\nolimits_{j\neq 3} \abs{b_{3 j}(t)} \\
&= -(\beta_A A+\beta_I I+\rho)-(\gamma_I+\eta+\alpha+\xi+2\mu)+\frac{A'}{A}+\gamma_A\frac{A}{R}+ \sigma\frac{A}{c I}  +\beta_A A\\
&\leq  -\epsilon \beta_I - \rho-\gamma_I-\eta-\alpha-\mu+\frac{\gamma_I+\eta+\alpha+\mu}{c}+\frac{A'}{A}+c\frac{I'}{c I}+c\frac{R'}{R} \displaybreak[0] \\[2ex]
%\end{align*}
%\begin{align*}
h_4(t)&= b_{44}(t)+\sum\nolimits_{j\neq 4} \abs{b_{4 j}(t)} \\
&=  \beta_A S -(\gamma_A + \sigma+\gamma_I+\eta+\alpha+\xi+2\mu)+\frac{S'}{S} +\rho\frac{S}{R}+ \beta_I \frac{S I}{A}\\[1ex]
&\leq  \beta_A-\gamma_I-\eta-\alpha+\frac{S'}{S}+\frac{A'}{A}+\frac{R'}{R}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I must do serious fixing in my document aha!